# Postgres jsonb nested array append

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have simple table with a `jsonb` column

```
CREATE TABLE things (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data jsonb
);
```

with data that looks like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
        "title": "thing",
        "things": [
            {
                "title": "thing 1",
                "moreThings": [
                    { "title": "more thing 1" }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

So how do I append inside of a deeply nested array like `moreThings`?

For single level nested array I could do this and it works:

```
UPDATE posts SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{things}', data->'things' || '{ "text": "thing" }', true);
```

But the same doesn't work for deeply nested arrays:

```
UPDATE posts SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{things}', data->'things'->'moreThings' || '{ "text": "thing" }', true)
```

How can I append to `moreThings`?

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine:

```
UPDATE things
SET data =
    jsonb_set(data,
              '{things,0,moreThings}',
              data->'things'->0->'moreThings' || '{ "text": "thing" }',
              TRUE
    )
WHERE id = 1;
```

If you have a table that consists only of a primary key and a `jsonb` attribute and you regularly want to manipulate this `jsonb` in the database, you are certainly doing something wrong. Your life will be much easier if you normalize the data some more.